# rails server won't start - `initialize': A JSON text must at least contain two octets! (JSON::ParserError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

Everything was working fine, but I ran out of diskspace. So, I restarted my computer, and now the rails server won't start. I've been searching for an hour, and I can't find anything online that seems to solve this.

Hoping some fresh eyes can lead me to the solution

Here is my terminal:

```
$ rails s
DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from require at /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74)
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.4 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Development log files too large. Running rake log:clear
DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from require at /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74)
audited 1193 packages in 11.916s

57 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    59: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    58: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    57: from /Users/Sam/App/app/bin/spring:14:in `<top (required)>'
    56: from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    55: from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    54: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    53: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    52: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    51: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    50: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    49: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    48: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    47: from /Users/Sam/App/app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    46: from /Users/Sam/App/app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    45: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    44: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    43: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    42: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    41: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    40: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    39: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    38: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    37: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    36: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    35: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    34: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    33: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    32: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    31: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    30: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    29: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    28: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    27: from config.ru:5:in `block in <main>'
    26: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
    25: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    24: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
    23: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
    22: from /Users/Sam/App/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
    20: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    19: from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    18: from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    17: from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    16: from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    15: from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    14: from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    13: from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    12: from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    11: from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    10: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
     9: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
     8: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
     7: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:41:in `block in <class:Engine>'
     6: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker.rb:35:in `bootstrap'
     5: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:47:in `bootstrap'
     4: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in `refresh'
     3: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:84:in `load'
     2: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
     1: from /Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
/Users/Sam/App/app/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize': A JSON text must at least contain two octets! (JSON::ParserError)
```

UPDATE 1
[I think this is related](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/pull/1399), but they say they fix the issue by 'deleting one of the files'. What file are they talking about?

UPDATE 2
I tried deleting the webpacker cache like this:

```
$ ls tmp/cache/webpacker
last-compilation-digest-development
rm tmp/cache/webpacker/last-compilation-digest-development
```

ran the server again, and still the same output.

Comment: I think this post explains what file and where it is.  Maybe read through it and see if it applies https://rossta.net/blog/how-to-use-webpacker-yml.html#cache_path

Comment: @RockwellRice thanks for the suggestion. I updated my question - I followed that link and tried to delete the cache, but still the same error. Any other ideas of what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve, I deleted `public/packs/manifest.json`, which was empty.

Then tried to start the server and everything ran fine...